# Is there an idiom like "stepping on someones toes" but way more serious?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I was look for something a little more damaging. Like..." stepping on someone's guts". The context is a sentence like "Don't you dare....[insert idiom]".

Any ideas?

Comment: Which is it, *toes* or *guts*?

Comment: Well. The original is toes... That's why I'm asking. I'm aware there is no such thing as stepping on someone's guts. Wait, is there?

Comment: I get it now. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "cross me."

> "Don't you dare cross me."
>
> - **Cross someone:** to oppose someone

Comment: Don’t **ever** fret the anonymous down-votes one bit. I wear the many I have received (and will continue to receive) proudly as badges of honor awarded by those lacking the English skills necessary to articulate just what it is they don’t like about questions and answers (not that there’s anything wrong with being inarticulate, mind you [I suppose]).  Anyway, here’s +1 to get you back to even for, among other things, giving me the chance to discuss anonymous down-votes and those who cast them.

Answer (score 4):

**"/touch/hit/strike/ a nerve"** sounds way more serious than "step on someone's toes".

> - "touch a (raw/sensitive) nerve - to make someone feel angry, upset, embarrassed, etc. [**MW**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hit/strike/touch%20a%20nerve)

**e.g.**

(a) I didn't mean any offense. I simply mentioned that I strongly disapprove of abortion.
(b) From her reaction, **I would say you've touched a nerve**."

Answer (score 1):

"Don't you dare **muscle in**"...on my project. If you try to muscle in, you'll be facing big trouble.

**Muscle in:** on someone or something. To try forcefully to displace someone or take over someone's property, interests, or relationships (idioms. thefreedictionary.com)

Comment: And then, of course, you've got the idiomatic, 'don't rain on my parade', which gives us a sodden version of 'stepping on one's shoes'. The idiom morphed into a song of that title by Jule Styne, sung by Barbara Streisand. I'll spare you my online rendition of the lyrics.

Answer (score 0):

According to The Free Dictionary (TFD):

> [*step on (somebody's) toes*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/step+on+toes): to say or do something which upsets
>   someone, especially by becoming involved in something which is their
>   responsibility

How about *steal someone's thunder*? From TFD:

> [*steal someone's
>   thunder*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thunder): to lessen
>   someone's force or authority. *What do you mean by coming in here and
>   stealing my thunder? I'm in charge here! / Someone stole my thunder by
>   leaking my announcement to the press.*

Your example:

> "Don't you dare *steal my thunder*!"

It is more damaging to *steal someone's thunder* than to *step on (somebody's) toes*. Also, *steal someone's thunder* means something like *step on (somebody's) toes* -- both involve a person doing something upsetting that is the responsibility of another person.

Comment: Stealing my thunder? Perish the thought. Rich, you wouldn't do that to an old chum, would you?

Comment: @PeterPoint Never! But would you mind if I asked to borrow it? After all, what are friends for? What?

Comment: Rich, follow the yellow brick road and thunder away to your heart's content. You can pick up flatulence tabs en route, what?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you give to help describe the notion you’re after, you maintain the original idiom's verb (*step [on]*) and increase the potential of doing more damage by changing the target from *toes* to one which when hit would normally cause more serious damage (*guts*).  As you’re fully aware, however (or else you wouldn’t have asked your question as you did), although your example serves nicely to show us what you seek, “step on my guts” is not at all idiomatic.

Instead of maintaining the idiom's verb and changing its target, perhaps you could instead consider maintaining the target and increase the potential damage to that same target by using a verb that normally conveys greater aggression and has greater damage-causing potential than *step/tread [on*], and two candidates for that verb that are idiomatic when used with “toes” are [**“stomp”**](https://books.google.com/books?id=zAH-Exhn7oMC&pg=PT47&dq=%22stomp+on+toes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS98nvxoPQAhVF7IMKHXCuBYEQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22stomp%20on%20toes%22&f=false) and [**“trample”**](https://books.google.com/books?id=EFxLAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA144&dq=%22trample+on+toes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja_d6YtYPQAhWCxYMKHUA9CtoQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22trample%20on%20toes%22&f=false), as in:

> "Don't you dare stomp on my toes!"
>     "Don't you dare trample on my
>   toes!"

or if necessary (i.e., your interlocutor has never experienced the painful difference) you could emphasize the distinction being made between *step* and *stomp* or *trample* by mentioning them together, especially with the appropriate inflection in your voice, perhaps as follows:

> “I can handle having my toes **stepped** on occasionally, but don't you ever dare to
>   **stomp/trample** on them!”

(An example of “stomp on [my] toes” is found in *Longarm #297: Longarm and Town-Taming Tess* by Tabor Evans and one of “trample on toes” in *The Substance of Faith: and Other Cotton Patch Sermons* by Clarence Jordan, both via *GoogleBooks*.)